# SQL - RANK() with multiple WHERE and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, rank, partition

I have a table with userid and date_accessed. (Multiple dates for each userid, but not the same number of dates for each.)

The data looks like this:

```
userid | date_accessed
A.     | 2019-01-01
B.     | 2019-01-02
A.     | 2019-01-03
A.     | 2019-01-04
B.     | 2019-01-04
```

There are a bunch of other columns in the db too but I'm not using them, but basically each there's one row for each day that each user performed an action.

I'd like to order the table so that it's partitioned by userid, with the date_accessed for each userid ranked chronologically.

```
userid | date_accessed | rank
A.     | 2019-01-01   | 1
A.     | 2019-01-03    | 2
A.     | 2019-01-04   | 3
B.     | 2019-01-02   | 1
B.     | 2019-01-04   | 2
```

My query is:

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT
    userid
  FROM table_1
  WHERE 
    date_accessed <= '2019-01-01'
    AND date_accessed >= '2019-01-10'
  HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT date_accessed) > 1
)

SELECT
    userid,
    date_accessed,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY userid
      ORDER BY date_accessed ASC)
FROM table_1
WHERE
    userid IN (SELECT * FROM a)
    AND date_accessed <= '2019-01-01'
    AND date_accessed >= '2019-01-10'
GROUP BY userid, date_accessed
```

The date range (the date_1 and date_2) cover a 10-day period. What's happening instead is that my query is just listing/ranking all 10 days for every single userid, even though not all userids should have corresponding entries for each of those dates. i.e. it looks like this:

```
userid | date_accessed | rank
A.     | 2019-01-01   | 1
A.     | 2019-01-02   | 2
A.     | 2019-01-03   | 3
A.     | 2019-01-04   | 4
A.     | 2019-01-05   | 5
...
A.     | 2019-01-10   | 10
B.     | 2019-01-01   | 1
B.     | 2019-01-02   | 2
```

and so on.

I thought maybe the problem was with my GROUP BYs, but the query doesn't run without the GROUP BYs — do I need to nest my RANK() somehow?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Hi Gordon, just updated my post! Does that help?

Comment: What do you mean with "the query doesn't run without the GROUP BYs" exactly? Is there an error message or unexpected result?

Comment: Are there more than 1 rows for each user and date?

Comment: @spencer7593, Ah sorry — I had the date in the wrong format in the above but it's correct in my actual query/in the actual database. I'll correct my post to avoid confusion

Comment: @forpas, yes, there can be more than 1 row for each user and date (if the same user performed the action multiple times on the same day) — that was also why I wanted the GROUP BY

Comment: Is this the exact code? Are you joining any other tables? The behavior that you describe is likely to happen with a cross join.

Comment: I define other_table with a WITH other_table AS (select etc etc) statement — is that an issue?

Comment: I don't know if I don't have your code. It's better to create a fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com to replicate your problem and post the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE that will return the distinct rows for each `user_id` and `date_accessed` filtered for the dates that you want and then use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the rank:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT userid, date_accessed
  FROM table_1
  WHERE date_accessed >= '2019-01-01' AND date_accessed <= '2019-01-10'
)
SELECT userid, date_accessed,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_accessed ASC) `rank`
FROM cte
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/caFeo5c4Try1q7FawHN7MC/0).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ROW_NUMBER instead of RANK?
What's the purpose of GROUP BY?

try this:

```
;WITH a as
(SELECT 
   userid,
   date_accessed,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_accessed ASC) AS rnk
FROM table
WHERE 
   userid IN ( SELECT * FROM other_table )
   AND date_accessed <= 'date_1'
   AND date_accessed >= 'date_2'
)
SELECT userid, date_accessed, rnk
from a
GROUP BY userid, date_accessed
```